# istream_iterator behaviour

Tags: c++, stl, istream-iterator

I have two pieces of code.They work properly when it is used alone in the `main()`.

```
vector<int> v;

cout << "Enter sequance of integers "<< "(press q to quit) : ";
istream_iterator<int> start_cin(cin);
istream_iterator<int> end_of_cin;
copy(start_cin,end_of_cin,back_inserter(v));

for ( vector<int>::iterator It = v.begin();It != v.end(); It++ )
    cout << *It << "\t";
cout << endl;
```

and

```
vector<string> vS;
cout << "Enter three strings : ";
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    vS.push_back(*istream_iterator<string>(cin));

ostream_iterator<string> sIt(cout,", ");
copy(vS.begin(),vS.end(),sIt);
cout << endl;
```

When these two part use together,i.e

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    // first part

    vector<int> v;

    cout << "Enter sequance of integers "<< "(press q to quit) : ";
    istream_iterator<int> start_cin(cin);
    istream_iterator<int> end_of_cin;
    copy(start_cin,end_of_cin,back_inserter(v));

    for ( vector<int>::iterator It = v.begin();It != v.end(); It++ )
        cout << *It << " \t";
    cout << endl;


    vector<string> vS;
    cout << "Enter three strings : ";
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        vS.push_back(*istream_iterator<string>(cin));

    ostream_iterator<string> sIt(cout,", ");
    copy(vS.begin(),vS.end(),sIt);

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

here first part worked but second part give output: `Enter Three Strings : , , ,`.
I want to know that what is the reason behind this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried changing vS to int and it printed some garbage values ...  Is it because the stream is corrupted .?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `copy()` has completed `cin` will be in an unreadable state (`!cin.good()`), due to the failed read of the "integer" `q`. This means the subsequent `for` loop will fail to read anything.

Add:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(); // To skip the unread "q"
```

before the `for` loop.

EDIT:

As commented by [James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze), check to ensure `"q"` was the cause of the termination of the `copy()`:

```
...

cin.clear();
string int_read_terminator;
cin >> int_read_terminator;
if ("q" != int_read_terminator)
{
    cerr << "Integer copy() failure: " << int_read_terminator << "\n";
}
else
{
    ...
```

Comment: What if the character wasn't a `q`?

Comment: @JamesKanze, then read it and ensure it was a `q` that caused the termination of the `copy()`. Will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've just encountered one of the problems with `input_iterator`: it
requires the entire file to be of one type.  There are several ways of
working around this; the most general is to insert a filtering streambuf
between the actual source and the stream.  Thus, for example, the first
part of your stream should terminate when you enter a single line with
just a `'q'`, something like:

```
class UntilQStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf*     mySource;
    char                myBuffer;
    bool                myIsAtStartOfLine;

protected:
    int underflow()
    {
        int                 results = mySource->sbumpc();
        if ( results == 'q' 
                && myIsAtStartOfLine
                && mySource->sgetc() == '\n' ) {
            mySource->sbumpc();     //  remove terminator line.
            results = traits_type::eof();
        }
        if ( results != traits_type::eof() ) {
            myBuffer = results;
            setg( &myBuffer, &myBuffer, &myBuffer + 1 );
        }
        return results;
    }

public:
    UntilQStreambuf( std::istream& source )
        :  mySource( source->rdbuf() )
        ,  myIsAtStartOfLine( true )
    {
    }
};
```

(I think `boost::iostream` has some support which would make this
significantly simpler to write.) You then set up a separate stream for
reading the numbers, using the `streambuf` from `std::cin` (or
whereever):

```
std::vector<int>
getNumbers( std::istream& source )
{
    UntilQStreambuf     localSB( source );
    std::istream        src( &localSB );
    std::vector<int>    results( (std::istream_iterator<int>( src )),
                                 (std::istream_iterator<int>()) );
    if ( !src.eof() ) {
        //  Some other error occurred...
    }
    return results;
}
```

By using a separate stream, the end condition won't be set in the
original stream, and you can continue with it later (perhaps using more
of the same technique).